# Cannot seem to float a list to the right inside a Bootstrap 4 row

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried so many CSS rules to try to get my list to float to the right inside a Bootstrap 4 row used in a custom Wordpress theme. I've tried using align-right on the row (both in my own CSS or using Bootstrap 4 classes) and using float:right on the list itself (both in my own CSS or using Bootstrap 4 classes). Its likely I did it wrong, as i may have lost track of combinations in my brain while testing :O

**Here is a fiddle of my structure:** https://jsfiddle.net/Katrina_B/o3u0cd9s/

*Please be sure to view in a wide browser space.*

**Objective:** I would like the for the navigation list (#navMenu) to align to the right inside the #fruits row (which incidentally should be purple!)

The only way I can achieve this is by changing the html so that #fruits is not a Bootstrap row, and instead set it to 100% width and float the list to the right, but that messes up the whole layout. And I managed to find a few other workarounds, but they caused problems with my script that keeps the #jumbo div at full viewport height (minus the #headerContainer height, which is dynamic).

There may be some other caveats that I have forgotten, where a managed it, but it negatively afected something else. But I think I've covered the basics and am currently at a loss.

Another factor that may be an issue, although since I replicated this problem here using plain html, is that ultimately the #menuNav will be generated via a Wordpress function as follows:

```
<?php
  wp_nav_menu( array(
  'theme_location'  => 'menu-1',
  'menu_id'         => 'primary-menu',
  ) );
?>
```

But i don't think this affects my current problem.

Thank you in advance for anyone who might be able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. width:100% makes the list go the length of the page, and text-align right will right align the list. I tested in Firefox and Chrome, and IE11.

```
#navMenu {
  background-color:#f7d765;
  padding:0 0 0 10px;
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan and thank you for your response and solution. It does indeed work in my fiddle, but it doesn't work on my real structure. When i read your suggestion i was shocked that i hadn't tried something so imple. So i must have tried that. So now i need to see what element I didn't replicate in my fiddle. 

However, your answer does work given the parameters i gave you (thank you!). I'll report back when I figure out what is different on my end!!??

Comment: Sounds good, if you reply to my comment I'll check it out when you update your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks enormously. Your answer is correct! So it turns out I HAD tried that a million times but it hadn't worked. It took me spending so much time to replicate the actual problem here in a fiddle to figure out it was definitely something Wordpress related. basically WP adds a div outside the list it generates, which caused the float-right rule not to work. I added the following line to the funtion specifiying NOT to include a container, and your solution finally works Thank you ! :)

`'container'  => false,`